# Want to sign transactions without metamask , how to protect private key?

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, metamask

I am building a full stack application which will include react js as front end and node js as backend and ethereum as blockchain platform. I have deployed my smart contract on a test network and now I want to integrate it with frontend ReactJS but I don't want to use metamask. I want that user just clicks on a button and the transactions gets signed inside the code and no wallet gets prompted on screen. But from internet resources , I have seen that Private keys are exposed in code so is there any way where I can hide my private keys and still sign transactions without metamask ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want that user just clicks on a button and the transactions gets signed inside the code and no wallet gets prompted on screen.

That is not how blockchain works. The user is in control of the key, not you. The wallet protects the private key because poor quality application developers cannot properly do this job.

I suggest you either

- Rethink your application so that you pay the gas fees and sign the transactions on behalf of your user
- Accept the fact you should not play around with the users' private keys
- ... or stop using blockchain for your application